# Get Pixel height of Centimetre unit CSS

Tags: javascript, pixel, css

We're writing our own web app and we need the user to have a (fairly) accurate visualisation of their printed documents **on-screen**. I'm using the centimetre unit in CSS to try and replicate an A4 page.

I need to work out the actual pixel height assigned to the following:

`max-height: 27cm;`

Is this possible in javaScript? I need the pixel height because I need to compare the offsetHeight to the max-height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, due to screens of differing size, resolution, and PPI, it wouldn't really be possible to display a real life sized view of a page that is consistent across screens. 
Not unless you could find the size of the pixels themselves, but I do not believe that is possible via JS.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks, I've not found anything thus far either. I'm pretty perplexed then how Google Docs is managing to maintain a perfect WYSIWYG layout regards to hardcopy via their Word component!?

Comment: They don't. The document I just looked at was not rendered on screen at actual size.

Comment: I havent used google docs, but surely the width/height of their document when displayed on screen is not exactly the width/height of a printed A4 sheet of paper. Or is it?

Comment: Well what I meant, more clearly sorry, was that the page breaking etc appears to be replicated accurately on screen as per the hardcopy.

Answer (score 0):

Short of asking the user to measure something with a known number of pixels and then type the matching number of cm or in — no.

I'm not aware of any API that exposes the system DPI to JavaScript, and most systems don't have their DPI correctly calibrated anyway.